# Eclipse doesn't seem to want to compile a new version of my class. I'm getting the same error even after (I think) fixing it

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm making an SQLite database for an Android App. I am extending the SQLiteOpenHelper.

The problem centers around this line

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + highscores + " (_id INT AUTOINCREMENT, level INT, moves INT);");
}
```

The top of the error returned (there is in fact a particularly gigantic error list, but I am assuming they stem from this error) is this

```
Failure 1 (AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY) on 0x1c0b98 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Highscores (_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, level INT, moves INT);'.
```

Easy fix, so I thought, but nope. I changed the line to

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + highscores + " (_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, level INT, moves INT);");
}
```

certain this would work. But I got the exact same error. Confused by this a tried playing with the statement a lot more, but always got exactly the same error. I can literally delete the entire line from my code and I get the same error.

Obviously I looked for duplicate classes, thinking I might be editing a copy but cannot see any.

Any help on this strange problem would be greatly apprechiated.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you added the primary key in your second attempt, but did you also add the INTEGER in your second attempt? This line works in my applications:

```
CREATE TABLE Person (_Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT, Budget CURRENCY, Active INTEGER);
```

Edit:

Just tested this using sqlite3 on the command line using adb and it seems to work:

```
> sqlite3 test.db
SQLite version 3.7.2
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Highscores (_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, level INT, moves INT);                        
Error: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Highscores (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, level INT, moves INT);                  
>
```

Answer (score 0):

May sound silly, but did you try deleting the device and recreating/launching so that the onCreate would be called again?

Comment: Not at all silly! An easier way to do this is changing the 4th parameter in your super() call in the constructor to change your databases's version number when using SQLiteOpenHelper.

Comment: I agree, if you've created the table already then any changes you make wont do diddly squat. If your following one of the many DB tutorials then you should have a version static propery, update this every time you make a change, and drop any existing tables.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different table name....

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing `INT` with `INTEGER` in your create statement.

More information here http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html.